# annoying div keeps 'Bouncing' from the top of the page

Tags: html

I am trying to set-up two div's. 
A long rectangular one to the left which will hold my company logo. 
and another thin div to fill the space not used by the logobox div.
you can check out my mock website at trinity-games.co.cc to see what I mean.

you may think's I've sorted it, but it's more of a hack. I'm using a transparent image for the navigational bar. I don't want this. I want a proper div. 
The inspect element tool on your chrome browser can show you what I mean.

I have tried various of ways to get the right hand div to fill the remaining space... I can do this successfully. but I have a new problem where by the left hand div, does not fit plush to the page ceiling. instead it takes the applied margin from the right hand div.

I just want to say that Web design is a new territory of mine. I'm use to Low level programming... this is very different...and annoying....

Answer (score 0):

```
#logoBox{ position:absolute;}

#NavigationBar{ margin-top:50px;}
```

Then remove `clip:rect(0px,0px,0px,0px);` from #logoBox

Comment: also set a background-color property of #NavigationBar to any color you wish so that you can see the changes